# How can $\mathbb{Z}_m[X]/p(X)$ be classified as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request

How can $\mathbb{Z}_m[X]/p(X)$ be classified as a ring when $p(X)$ is a polynomial, say degree $\le$ 3? In particular, can we find a good indicator of whether it is a UFD/PID/field?

For instance,

- I have heard it said that if $p(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ degree 2 or 3 if and only if it has no roots if and only if it is a field. But I can't find a proof of this (and might have got the last part wrong)
- If $p(X)$ is reducible, then clearly the quotient cannot even be a domain because the product of those two things equals zero.

Is there a (reference to) a more complete theory than the bits I have picked up here and there?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_m$ your notation for the finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ or does it have something to do with the $m$-adic integers (for $m$ prime)? In the first case, the ring is not even an integral domain when $m$ is composite.

Comment: @Mastrem First case

Comment: If $m$ is composite, then $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain, which means it isn't a UFD or PID or a field. If $m$ is prime, then $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, so $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a PID, so if $P$ is an irreducible polynomial, $(P)$ is a maximal ideal and $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}[X])/(P)$ is a field. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @Mastrem That idea. Stronger yet, Z/mZ is a field implies Z/mZ[X] is ED. Can you prove your other two claims? What can we say when $(P)$ is not maximal?

Comment: Prove my two claims? This is all standard theory, look into any basic algebra book. RE your last question: Suppose that $P=P_1P_2$ is reducible, then what is the product of the residue classes of $P_1$ and $P_2$ in the quotient ring equal to?